# Where does the peak pressure increase due to an aircraft flying overhead reach the ground?

Tags: aerodynamics

Is the center of the pressure increase at the ground directly under the airplane?
I have read in multiple sources that it is and there are arguments to support that. However one might also expect the effect of the air disturbance from the plane to be delayed, at least by the speed of sound, before it reached the ground.
If the plane was close to the ground, what would be the effect of the downwash hitting the ground?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's usually the two trailing vortices that hit the ground first, since they each induce a downward velocity component on the other, but calculating the speed they move depends on the plane's geometry, weight & speed - more of an engineering calculation.

Comment: This question could be a better fit on Aviation SE.

Comment: @D. Halsey, I noticed that you didn't address the question of the center of pressure being directly under the plane. Perhaps this issue has not received much attention because it's not important. It seems you agree that the downwash will reach the ground at some point behind the airplane.

Comment: Any pressure perturbations would take some finite time to reach the ground, so they would lag behind the plane to some degree. I expect they would be very small and difficult to measure though. The trailing vortices are a very different story! I've been below the flight path of planes that have just taken off (a mile or two away) and witnessed the vortices hitting plants & trees with gale-force winds!

Comment: I have tested this with OpenFOAM CFD which shows that the downward momentum is all in the wake, but I don't have a lot of confidence in my results. It seems unlikely that the momentum would be split between the downwash and some other mechanism that delivers pressure to the ground directly below the airplane such that the sum is equal to the weight of the plane.

Comment: Perhaps there is a pressure wave traveling at the speed of sound that reaches the surface under the aircraft in addition to the wake that reaches the ground well behind the aircraft.